# What are the supported encodings for Java's SAXBuilder?

Tags: java, xml

In using [SAXBuilder](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder.html) to read in an XML document, what are the supported character encodings that the reader can support.

For example;

- windows-1251
- UTF-8
- etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java supported encodings will depend on the JVM. Remember that the `InputStream` class is used by the readers, so depending on your JVM, different encodings will work.

See an exemplary list here: [Java 6 Supported Encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)